# Could an ADSL router/modem loss routing functionality?

Tags: router, internet, isp, adsl

From several years ago, I have **TP-LINK TD-8810** ADSL modem/router. From about five days ago, I noticed that the Internet Connectivity could not able to open specific websites, such as Google for example, while another websites are opened partially, i.e there is some resources such as images and JS files could not be loaded such as StackOverflow and Facebook and finally, there are websites don't be affected with this issue at all such as Bing and proxysite.

I have made test from another devices in my LAN such as mobile devices (I use Linksys WRT54G as a WiFi router) and it always give the same issue.

I realized that my ISP block the service for me by a mean of proxy. However, today, I have got another router of a friend, Huawei HG531 V1, and I supplied it with my connection PPPoE data and I have found everything has worked fine!

I have reset the the old router, and setting the ADSL connection data again but the issue is the same.

The question is: Could it possible that my old router has been got faulty in routing and this fault is kept for specific websites? Or does it a trick made against me from the ISP (Don't wonder, I'm talking from Egypt) due to a complain for unsolved ADSL problem reported since last May 2016?

Comment: No; What you describe is not possible.

Comment: @Ramhound So, could it be a trick from the ISP? or what could you advice?

Comment: Could what be a trick?

Comment: Something like blocking applying an access rule for my router's MAC address, Indeed I don't know if the ISP could able to determine the manufacturer of my router or not. However, the new router that I use, is one of the ISP offer in there packages, so the ISP could know its MAC . @Ramhound

Comment: Your problems are a configuration problem on the modem and not anything your ISP is or is not doing

Comment: Sadly routers don't last forever.  By swapping in your friends Huawei then it shows your existing router is getting old and flakey.  Might be time for a new one.  (commenting because "buy a new one" is a solution but doesn't answer the question)

Comment: @Criggie but it could able to maintain an ADSL connection. It does not has power loss, for example, and the most weird thing here, the specificity of websites affected! I think that the majority of hardware problems or even software should give random symptoms for the websites not specific one! However, I will think in buying new one but after testing it with clone its MAC address on another ADSL subscriber line (that friend too). It was with me since 2006!

Comment: So you've had 10 years use out of it, which is pretty good.   You have proved that its acting "weird" and a replacement doesn't.  How much time do you want to invest?  Best to just cut your losses and replace it.

Comment: I think I may have seen this problem and IIRC I think it may have been an MTU issue and that could be set on the router. Try different values 1492, 1400 1500  try lower values maybe.

Comment: @barlop I'm testing your solution right not. I tried 1500, and I'm now on 1400. It would be promising solution. I will tell you the result after confirmation.

Comment: @barlop You have got the solution I used [this resource](http://www.bestyoucanget.com/optimizemtu.htm) to check the best MTU. Additionally, I will call the ISP's technical support asking them about it. Please submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: I have outdone myself!

Comment: what turned out to be your optimal MTU?  When it happened to me it was the router manufacturer that had that solution, rather than the ISP.. The router was a netgear. My ISP's router was fine.  My ISP is really good and they only provide routers they know are very reliable.. In the UK some find that netgear doesn't seem like the most reliable

Comment: Nevertheless, once or twice i've tried netgear(it's not one my ISP provides or favours), and on one of those occasions I ran into that issue, and netgear had that solution regarding MTU. (note netgear tech support is only free for first month last time i checked). So, points there are if you have a great really reliable ISP with great tech support then they may  provide routers they have found to be most reliable.. And the other point there is besides ISP tech support, you can try the router manufacturer tech support.

Comment: @barlop I think that the base of the issue is an issue regarding my telephone line that carries the ADSL, there is problems in the attainable rate of the line and already I have posted a complain about this but they delay to offer solution since 27 May 2016!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47726/discussion-between-barlop-and-ss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have seen this problem of being able to access some websites and not others, (when the websites you can't access are up / up for others), and IIRC I think it may have been an MTU issue and that could be set on the router. Try different values 1492, 1400 1500 try lower values maybe.

OP found this link and that it was useful http://www.bestyoucanget.com/optimizemtu.htm